# Track count of the new and updated records seperatly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Currently working on a project where any admin can import a xlsx product sheet into active record. I've developed it so that the xlsx parser hands each unique product row to a job which either updates an existing product or creates a new based on the attributes given.

I would like to keep track of the count of products either updated and created per sheet imported, assets added etc, to display in the admin panel.

The method i use now is simply creating events with an associated product id's that respond to a `save` record conditional, which i then count up and display after the import is done.

```
if product.save
  product.events.new(payload: 'save')
end
```

The problem with this technique is that i can't differentiate between if the product is new or has been updated.

Are there better techniques that are more suitable to achieve counting products saved while differentiating between if its updated or new?

TDLR;
Importing products to active record (1 job per product) from an excel sheet. What are the better practise's/techniques for keeping count of new and updated records seperatly per import.

Comment: Quick idea that I haven't tested (and might not be the best one for your needs): you could compare the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns: if they're the same, it's a record that was just created, if they're different, it's a record that was updated. (now that I think about it, this might not be a very clean solution)

Comment: Thats actually a very good idea. Will test it now. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: It worked as a charm! Post it as answer and i will mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices here:

A simple option, as per my comment, is simply to check the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns after the record is saved. If they're equal, it's a new record, if not, it means the record already existed and was updated. You would have something along these lines:

```
if product.created_at == product.updated_at
   new_product_count += 1
else
  updated_product_count += 1
end
```

However, there might be better ways to do this. Just as an example: If I understand correctly you keep track of the number of saved products by creating a new 'save' event. You could instead have two types of events: `created` and `updated`. (This would have the added benefit of allowing you to count how many times a product has been updated since it was created)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you but in these cases I use `persisted?` method.

```
person = Person.new(id: 1, name: 'bob')
person.persisted? # => false
```